# How to parse PHP variable pulled from XML file?

Tags: php, xml

First, I'm pulling text from one XML file which is just a name and putting it in a `$name` variable.

Then I'm pulling some other text from a different XML file and this text contains a variable, let's say:

```
<list>
 <wishes>
  <id>001</id>
  <text>Happy birthday, '.$name.'</text>
 </wishes>
</list>
```

As you see, I already tried to format it in a way which should conc... conat... parse it, but it doesn't. Once I include it in something as simple as this:

```
foreach ($people->user as $person) {

   if ($person->date == date('d.m')) {

      $name = $person->name;

         foreach ($list->wishes as $wish) {

            $text = $wish->text;

      }

   echo 'Wishes for '.$name.'.';
   echo 'Wish example: '.$text.' something something';

}
```

The result will be:

```
Wishes for John.
Wish example: Happy birthday, '.$name.' something something
```

It will treat the variable as plain text instead of replacing it with the actual name of the person.

So how do I force it to replace the `$name` variable with the actual name if the variable is contained in an XML file? BTW, I also tried to include `echo` or `print` in various places - inside the XML file, by setting another variable that would print the content of the XML file and then set that variable as the one that's echoed in the end - no luck, it just keeps treating it as text.

Comment: would `$wish->text = str_replace('$name',$person->name,$wish->text)` be enough? I feel allowing arbitary variable replacement or even using eval could open up your code to explotation. Where does the original text come from anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this, so it's well-formed XML:

```
<text>Happy birthday, <var name="name" /></text>
```

Then parse your XML file like this (PHP short-array form):

```
$memory = [
    'name' => 'Christopher Robin',
    //'other' => 'values',
    //'go' => 'here',
];

$parsed = preg_replace_callback(
    '#<var name="(.*?)"\\s*/>#',
    function ($matches) use ($memory) {
        if (array_key_exists($matches[1], $memory)) {
            return $memory[$matches[1]];
        }
        return ''; // A referred variable is not in $memory!
    }
);
```

This should get you going (I'm not sure, off the top of my head, whether it's $matches[1] or $matches[0] - you can print out $matches to check which it is).

Your XML is now:

```
<text>Happy birthday, Christopher Robin</text>
```

Or you could declare a *stream XML parser* to process every tag and output it appropriately. Here, you would only output `text` to stdout, while `var` would return with the same method as above. The result would thus be the text "Happy birthday, Christopher Robin".

Comment: I'm not sure that PO is able to change the syntax of the variable to what you propose.

Comment: @Michael He did write "As you see, I already tried to format it", so I assumed he had control. By changing the regexp to #'\.\$(.*?)\.'#  however, the answer should work with the syntax as it is now.

Comment: @LSemi cool - just wanted to point it out in case you'd missed it. :)